# How do I run python code in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, compiling, source-code

I'm learning python so I may get my foot in the door for a programming career.  I'm using the gedit text editor to write the code, however I don't know how to execute the code on ubuntu.  If anyone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate as much help as I'm able to get.

Comment: Do you know how to use the terminal? Commands like `cd`, `ls`, etc.?

Comment: I'm still learning linux. I've been using it on and off for about 7 years but I don't have that much familiarity with it just yet. But I am always willing to learn

Comment: I swear it's not a duplicate. I read that persons question.  My question is not related to it.

Comment: @wxl we haven't got around to actually running the program, so no errors yet. :)

Comment: @muru despite the weird name, it does actually explain how to run the program, i.e. as referred to in the OP "execute the code."

Comment: @JacobVlijm I strongly recommend making a habit of using the versioned name - in case you ever move to Arch Linux.

Comment: @muru Ah, I see, in Arch Linux, python is not python2?

Comment: @JacobVlijm [It is `python3`](https://www.archlinux.org/news/python-is-now-python-3/). They broke the status quo and I think forced [this recommendation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). Fedora also intend to migrate soon, I think.

Comment: @muru Thanks! that is useful information. I think I will replace my comment.

Comment: I really suggest using Idle (python2) or Idle 3 (python3), then you can test your code with pressing F5.

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. If you remember where you saved the Python code file (say as `first.py` in the `Desktop` folder), use the following command to run it:

```
python2 ~/Desktop/first.py
```

If you're using Python 3.X replace `python2` with `python3` in the above command. On Ubuntu, `python2` and `python` are the same, but it's always good practice to explicitly specify which version you're using.

You can also simply run `python2` or `python3` to get to an interactive shell. Another option is to use [IPython Notebooks](http://ipython.org/index.html).

Comment: I just tried to run it and I got this error: python3: can't open file 'Desktop/leaningpython.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: yes it's on my desktop that is usually where I save my documents until I move them into another folder

Comment: OK, try: `python3 ~/Desktop/leaningpython.py`. Also, please post the output of `ls ~/Desktop -l`.

Comment: as I run it all I'm getting is this:  File "/home/darkxearo/Desktop/learningpython.py", line 1
    >>> "This text really won't do anything"
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @SeanKirkland there you have it. You haven't written valid Python code yet. :)

Comment: ok so once I do then I can run things properly. Am I right?

Comment: @SeanKirkland yes.